# Yii2 batchInsert eats all server memory

Tags: php, memory-management, yii2

If I insert million rows in 100 batch inserts than every iteration memory_usage getting bigger and then php memory error occurs. It is connected with Yii insert command, because if I comment insert operation memory_usage are stable.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i ++) {
    ...
    Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
        ->batchInsert(static::tableName(), $columns, $rows)
        ->execute();
    echo memory_get_usage();
}
```

I've tried do disable debug mode and it's not helped.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: It's seems like all queries cashed somewhere. How to disable it? BTW, $enableQueryCache is disabled. I think memory allocated for query must be released when it ended.

Comment: Some more info: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/9269

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that problem is in logger of Yii2. Just try to use something like that:

common/components/EmptyLogger.php:

```
<?php
namespace common\components;

use yii\log\Logger;

class EmptyLogger extends Logger
{
    public function log($message, $level, $category = 'application')
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and then in your action of your controller include next code at the beginning:

```
Yii::setLogger(new EmptyLogger());
```

of course also add it in your uses:

```
use common\components\EmptyLogger;
```

after all you will receive something like that:

console\controllers\TempController.php:

```
<?php

namespace console\controllers;

use common\components\EmptyLogger;
use Yii;
use yii\console\Controller;

class TempController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        Yii::setLogger(new EmptyLogger());
        ...

        Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
            ->batchInsert(static::tableName(), $columns, $rows)
            ->execute();
        ...

    }
}
```

Hope it helps. But actually it's not the best solution. Just a hack..

Comment: Your are absolutely right. The problem is in Logger. And even if you set "exportInterval" property to smaller number it will be passed to Target object and still eat all memory. I've changed configuration and disable FileTarget for DB queries and debug module.